# sudo NOPASSWD : no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Tags: ubuntu, безопасность, sudo

Столкнулся с проблемой при правке конфига sudo

```
User_Alias      GRBACK = odoouser
GRBACK  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Работает нормально
При попытке указать определённую команду

```
User_Alias      GRBACK = odoouser
GRBACK  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/backups/odoo/system_backup.sh
```

Вылетает

```
skif@vadim:~$ sudo -s
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/odoouser: ошибка синтаксиса near line 3 <<<
sudo: parse error in  near line 3
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики
```

Функционал порезали?

```
root@vadim:/home/skif# dpkg -l | grep sudo
sudo 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2
root@vadim:/home/skif# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: На будущее: редактировать sudoers надо командой sudoedit

Comment: а по сути вопроса?

Comment: Да, действительно, если тоже сделать через sudoedit ошибка уходит. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Править файлы в sudoers.d только sudoedit

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/125114)

Comment: @BlackWitcher тем не менее автор написал, что именно это ему каким-то образом помогло, хотя это очень странно (это не должно было помочь, лол)

Comment: 1. Ответ выполнен в виде цитаты, в т.ч. с указанием вашего ника и времени (andreymal 14 минут назад), что не есть гуд. Мой комментарий - призыв автору ответа исправить ответ должным образом, т.к. если у кого-то еще возникнет аналогичный вопрос, то данный ответ ну уж никак нельзя назвать верхом понятности.
2. Автор вопроса не принял пока предложенный ответ.

Comment: Убрал "лишнее".